# On removing offensive and aggressive speech in comments

Tags: support, moderation, comments, flagging

Is it possible to mark comments as spam, aggressive or offensive; in the same way that posts can be?

There's one I've just noticed that is a good candidate simply by the use of language ie words generally understood to be offensive.

Comment: If you place your cursor on the left side of the comment, an arrow (for an up vote) and a flag appear. Press the flag, and a series of options appear. You can then flag the comment as rude, not constructive, etc. This feature is on all SE sites, including Philosophy SE

Comment: @cicero: Ok, thks; I just tried it: I'm using a smartphone and all I see on the left of the comment is a small triangle to vote up - no flag. I guess it's only supported on proper computers, or the like.

Comment: if you press the comment on the smartphone you get a series of options bellow. On the left is the upvote button, but in the middle there is a flag option. Press this flag, and the options described above comes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Desktop version

If you hover the comment, you see on the left a triangle for upvoting and a flag for flagging.

#### Mobile version

This is not possible. In most mobile browsers you can however tick a checkbox 'request desktop version', and then you can do like in the desktop version.

#### Android app

First tap the comment. Then, in the top menu there is an option 'flag'.

#### iOS app (thanks Cicero)

If you press the comment you get a series of options bellow. On the left is the upvote button, but in the middle there is a flag option. Press this flag, and the options for flagging come.